# Pizza Delivery System

Tags: c++, object-oriented, inheritance

I have made this code as my summers vacation project in Turbo C++ (I know its old and outdated, but that's what they teach us in our school).

The code allows users to order different pizzas and even create them using ingredients they like. After that the pricing is displayed based on the amount and serving of the ingredients.
The admin panel allows you to put offers in the 'offers' section and also edit them. You can also view the number of orders for the session and also the total income.
The admin panel requires a predefined login id and password to be accessed.
Please tell me what you think! I would like to know if there are any improvements that I can make in the code.

Note:
the login for the admin panel is:

USER ID : 123

PASSWORD : 321

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


static int count = (1); //tracks order number;
class base_pizza    //defines basic ingridients
{
protected:      //or they are unaccessible by child class
unsigned int price;
int size;
int capscicum;
int tomatoes;
int mushrooms;
int olives;
int tikka_chicken;
int roast_chicken;
int cheese;


base_pizza()   //constructor to define base prices
    {
    price=0;
    size=60;
    capscicum=50;
    tomatoes=50;
    mushrooms=50;
    olives=50;
    tikka_chicken=70;
    roast_chicken=80;
    cheese=40;
    }


    public:

    int choose_base()   //choose base
    {
    char opt;

    cout<<"\nSelect size of the pizza(S/M/L):\t";
    cin>>opt;

    switch (opt)
        {
        case 's':
        case 'S':
                return 1;

        case 'm':
        case 'M':
                return 2;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
                return 3;

        default:
                return 1;
        }
    }

    int admin_edit()
        {
        int edit;
        cout<<"\nEnter New value:\t";
        cin>>edit;
        return edit;
        }
};


class customize: public base_pizza //defines customization functions
{
protected:
int serv_capscicum;
int serv_tomatoes;
int serv_mushrooms;
int serv_olives;
int serv_tikka_chicken;
int serv_roast_chicken;
int serv_cheese;
int serv_size;
public:

customize()     //default serving of ingridients
    {
    serv_size=1;
    serv_capscicum=1;
    serv_tomatoes=1;
    serv_mushrooms=1;
    serv_olives=1;
    serv_tikka_chicken=0;
    serv_roast_chicken=0;
    serv_cheese=1;
    }

int choose_serv()   //function to choose serving of each object
    {
    char x;
       //   int serv;
    cin>>x;
    switch (x)
        {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
                return 0;

        case 's':
        case 'S':
                return 1;

        case 'm':
        case 'M':
                return 2;

        case 'l':
        case 'L':
                return 3;

        default:
                return 1;
        }

     // return serv;
    }

void calc_price()   //calculates price
    {
    int pricet=0;   //0 to avoid junk value
    pricet+=(serv_size)*(size);
    pricet+=(serv_capscicum)*(capscicum);
    pricet+=(serv_tomatoes)*(tomatoes);
    pricet+=(serv_mushrooms)*(mushrooms);
    pricet+=(serv_olives)*(olives);
    pricet+=(serv_tikka_chicken)*(tikka_chicken);
    pricet+=(serv_roast_chicken)*(roast_chicken);
    pricet+=(serv_cheese)*(cheese);
    price=pricet;
    }

int ret_price()
    {
    return price;
    }
void disp_price()   //displays price
    {
    cout<<price;
    }

void edit_base()    //function to edit size of base

    {
    int x;
       //   cout<<"\nEnter the size of the Base: ";
    x=choose_base();
    serv_size=x;
    }

void edit_capscicum()   //function to edit serving of capsicum
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Capscicum: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_capscicum=x;
    }

void edit_tomatoes()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Tomatoes: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_tomatoes=x;
    }

void edit_mushrooms()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Mushrooms: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_mushrooms=x;
    }

void edit_olives()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Olives: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_olives=x;
    }

void edit_tikka_chicken()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Chicken tikka: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_tikka_chicken=x;
    }

void edit_roast_chicken()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Roasted Chicken: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_roast_chicken=x;
    }

void edit_cheese()
    {
    int x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the serving of Cheese: ";
    x=choose_serv();
    serv_cheese=x;
    }

};


class veg_extra: public customize
{
void veg_extra1()   //default servs for predefined pizza
    {
    serv_size=1;
    serv_capscicum=2;
    serv_tomatoes=1;
    serv_mushrooms=2;
    serv_olives=2;
    serv_tikka_chicken=0;
    serv_roast_chicken=0;
    serv_cheese=1;
    }
public:
void call() //function to call the private function for servs
    {
    veg_extra1();
    }

};

class nveg_extra: public customize
{
void nveg_extra1()
    {
    serv_size=1;
    serv_capscicum=1;
    serv_tomatoes=1;
    serv_mushrooms=2;
    serv_olives=1;
    serv_tikka_chicken=2;
    serv_roast_chicken=1;
    serv_cheese=1;
    }
public:
void call()
    {
    nveg_extra1();
    }

};

char offers[8][50];
static int ctr=0;   //keeps count of number of offers
int pin=0;
static long int sales=0;//total sales
char adr[80]={"Shop-5,Ground Floor, Unity One Mall, Janakpuri, New Delhi,                 110019"};
char phn[11]={"9818114547"};
char mail[30]={"contact@palacefoods.com"};

class admin: public base_pizza
{

int user[3];
int pass[3];

public:
admin()     //accepted admin logins
    {
    user[0]=123;
    pass[0]=321;
    user[1]=456;
    pass[1]=654;
    user[2]=789;
    pass[2]=987;
    }

int retuser(int i)
    {
    return user[i];
    }
int retpass(int i)
    {
    return pass[i];
    }

void admin_panel()
    {
    int r;

    clrscr();
    cout<<"\t\t\tADMIN PANEL\n";
    cout<<"\nPlease choose an option:";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t1.Check Total Sales";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t2.Add Offers";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t3.Edit Offers";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t4.Edit Contact options";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t5.Exit Admin Panel";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t6.LOGOUT\n";
    cout<<"\n-->> ";
    cin>>r;

    switch(r)
        {
        case 1:
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\n\n\n";
            cout<<"Total sales for the day have been Rs. ";
            cout<<sales;
            getch();
            break;

        case 2:
            clrscr();
            cout<<"Enter the new offer below:\n";
            gets(offers[ctr]);
            cout<<"\n\n\n";
            cout<<"Offer Posted in 'Offers' section.\n";
            ctr++;
            getch();
            break;

        case 3:
            int n;
            clrscr();
            cout<<"Enter the Offer Number to be edited: ";
            cin>>n;
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            n=n-1;
            if(n>=ctr)
                {
                cout<<"\n*No offer found*\n";
                }
            else
                {
                cout<<"\nENTER NEW OFFER BELOW:\n";
                gets(offers[n]);
                cout<<"\n\n***Offers updated***\n";
                }
            getch();
            break;

        case 4:
            int opt,key=1;
            while(key==1)
            {
            clrscr();
            cout<<"Choose an option:\n";
            cout<<"\n1.Edit Phone Number\n";
            cout<<"\n2.Edit Email Adress\n";
            cout<<"\n-->>";
            cin>>opt;

            switch(opt)
                {
                case 1:
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n";
                    cout<<"Enter new phone number: ";
                    gets(phn);
                    cout<<"\n\n";
                    cout<<"Phone Number updated";
                    getch();
                    key=0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n";
                    cout<<"Enter new Email: ";
                    gets(mail);
                    cout<<"\n\n";
                    cout<<"Email Adress updated";
                    getch();
                    key=0;
                    break;

                default:
                    key=1;

                }
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        case 6:
            pin=0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


    }

};

char phno[20][11],addr[20][40];
void get_details()
{
clrscr();
cout<<"Please enter the following details:";
cout<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Your Address : ";
gets(addr[count]);
cout<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Your Phone Number : ";
gets(phno[count]);
cout<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Details successfully entered\n";
getch();
}

void main()
{
int ch,x,y,s,k;

menu:
clrscr();
cout<<"\t\t\t\t------------\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t       *Pizza Palace*";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t------------\n";

cout<<"\n\t\t\t  Welcome to Pizza Palace!\n";
cout<<"Order No. : "<<count;
cout<<"\n*Please choose an option from the list:\n";
cout<<"\n\n\t1.Order Now!";
cout<<"\n\n\t2.Offers";
cout<<"\n\n\t3.Contact Us";
cout<<"\n\n\t4.About Us";
cout<<"\n\n\t5.Admin Login";
cout<<"\n\n\t6.EXIT";
cout<<"\n\n--->> ";

cin>>ch;

switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
        clrscr();
        int ch1;
        cout<<"\nSelect an option to proceed\n";
        cout<<"\n1.Choose from our range of exciting Pizzas!";
        cout<<"\n\n2.Make your own Pizza!";

        choosech1:
        cout<<"\n\n--->> ";
        cin>>ch1;

        switch(ch1)
        {
        case 1:
            int k;
            clrscr();
            cout<<"Which pizza would you like "
            <<"your tastebuds to delight in?\n";
            cout<<"\n1.Veg Extraveganza";
            cout<<"\n2.Non Veg Extraveganza\n";
            cin>>k;

            switch(k)
            {
            case 1:

                veg_extra ob1;
                ob1.call();
                clrscr();
                cout<<"\nYou selected Veg "
                <<"Extraveganza\n";
                cout<<endl;
                ob1.edit_base();
                ob1.calc_price();
                cout<<"\nAmount Due: Rs.";
                ob1.disp_price();
                getch();
                get_details();
                cout<<"\n\t\t\tThank you for"
                <<" ordering\n";
                cout<<"\t\t\tPlease keep Rs. ";
                ob1.disp_price();
                cout<<" ready.";
                cout<<"\n*Your order will arrive"
                <<" in under 45 mins, or its free!";
                cout<<endl;
                count++;
                sales+=ob1.ret_price();
                getch();
                clrscr();
                goto menu;
                 // break;
            case 2:
                nveg_extra ob2;
                ob2.call();
                clrscr();
                cout<<"\nYou selected Non Veg "
                <<"Extraveganza\n";
                cout<<endl;
                ob2.edit_base();
                ob2.calc_price();
                cout<<"\nAmount Due: Rs.";
                ob2.disp_price();
                getch();
                get_details();
                cout<<"\n\t\t\tThank you for"
                <<" ordering\n";
                cout<<"\t\t\tPlease keep Rs. ";
                ob2.disp_price();
                cout<<" ready.";
                cout<<"\n*Your order will arrive"
                <<" in under 45 mins, or its free!";
                cout<<endl;
                count++;
                sales+=ob2.ret_price();
                getch();
                clrscr();
                goto menu;


            default:
                break;
            }



        case 2:
            int r;
            customize ob3;
            editor:
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\t\t\tMake you own pizza!\n";
            cout<<"How to go about it:\n";
            cout<<"\t*Once presented with an"
            <<" ingredient, choose a serving:\n"
            <<"\t\tS - Small\n\t\tM - Medium\n"
            <<"\t\tL - Large\n\t\tN - Skip (remove)\n"
            <<"Once you complete, the final price will"
            <<" be displayed, if you are satisfied "
            <<"you\ncan continue, or you can remake "
            <<"the pizza\n";

            ob3.edit_base();
            ob3.edit_capscicum();
            ob3.edit_tomatoes();
            ob3.edit_mushrooms();
            ob3.edit_olives();
            ob3.edit_tikka_chicken();
            ob3.edit_roast_chicken();
            ob3.edit_cheese();

            ob3.calc_price();

            cout<<"\n\nYour Order sums up at Rs. ";
            ob3.disp_price();

            cout<<"\n\nDo you want to continue, or"
            <<" edit your order?\n"
            <<"\t1.Continue\n"
            <<"\t2.Edit Order\n";

            cin>>r;

            if(r==1)
                {

                }
            else
                {
                goto editor;
                }

            cout<<"\n\n\nYour order sums up to Rs. ";
            ob3.disp_price();
            getch();
            get_details();
            cout<<"\nThank you for ordering\n";
            cout<<"\nPlease keep Rs. ";
            ob3.disp_price();
            cout<<" ready with you.";
            cout<<"\nYour order will arrive under"
            <<" 45 mins, or its free!";
            count++;
            sales+=ob3.ret_price();
            getch();
            clrscr();
            goto menu;

               //   break;
        default:
            goto choosech1;
        }


          //    break;
    case 2:
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\t\t\t\tOFFERS\n";
        for(int i=0; i<ctr; ++i)
            {
            cout<<i+1<<".";
            puts(offers[i]);
            cout<<endl;
            }
        getch();
        break;
    case 3:
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\t\t\t\tCONTACT US";
        cout<<"\n\n\n";
        cout<<"ADDRESS: ";
        puts(adr);
        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Place order on phone:-\n";
        cout<<"\tPhone Number : ";
        cout<<phn;
        cout<<"\n\n";
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Email : ";
        cout<<mail;

        getch();
        break;
    case 4:
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\t\t\t\tAbout\n\n";
        cout<<"This program has been made by Jyotinder "
        <<"Singh and Rachit Jain, of class XII-A as their "
        <<"Computer Science Project for the year 2016-2017.";
        cout<<"\n\n";
        cout<<"Salient features of the program:\n";
        cout<<"\n\t1.User friendly interface."
        <<"\n\n\t2.Dynamic Pricing system - No prefixed prices!"
        <<"\n\n\t3.Prices calculated based on servings you choose for each object."
        <<"\n\n\t4.Each ingridient defined as separate member of the class."
        <<"\n\n\t5.Admin Panel."
        <<"\n\n\t6.Admin can add and edit offers."
        <<"\n\n\t7.Track of total number of orders for that day."
        <<"\n\n\t8.Track of total sales for the day";

        getch();
        break;
    case 5:
        admin log;
        if(pin!=0)
            {
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\nYou are already logged in\n";
            getch();
            log.admin_panel();
            }
        else if(pin==0)
            {
            int id,cred;
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\t\t\tADMIN LOGIN";
            cout<<"\n\n\n";
            cout<<"\t\t\t";
               cout<<"USER ID: ";
            cin>>id;
            for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
                {
                if(id==log.retuser(i))
                    {

                    cout<<"\n\t\t\t";
                    cout<<"PASSWORD: ";
                    cin>>cred;

                    if(cred==log.retpass(i))
                        {
                        pin=1;
                        log.admin_panel();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        cout<<"\n\t\t\t";
                        cout<<"Password "
                        <<"doesn't match\n";
                        getch();
                        goto menu;
                         // break;
                        }

                    }
                else
                    {
                    continue;
                    }
                }


            }
        goto menu;
         // break;
    case 6:
        exit(0);

    default:
        break;
    }


goto menu;
   //   getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- Avoid goto based loop : replace `menu:` and final `goto menu` by a loop (`while(1) { ... }` for example). Inside your `switch` case, use `break` instead of `goto menu`. It will increase readability and maintenability: your function is really big, avoid many exit point
- Avoid big function: you have a very big `main` function. You can divide it in many subfunction, for example, one for get choice of user:

  ```
  ch = getUseChoice();
  ```

  and

  ```
  int getUserChoice()
  {
      int ch = 0;
      clrscr();
      cout<<"\t\t\t\t------------\n";
      cout<<"\t\t\t       *Pizza Palace*";
      cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t------------\n";

      cout<<"\n\t\t\t  Welcome to Pizza Palace!\n";
      cout<<"Order No. : "<<count;
      cout<<"\n*Please choose an option from the list:\n";
      cout<<"\n\n\t1.Order Now!";
      cout<<"\n\n\t2.Offers";
      cout<<"\n\n\t3.Contact Us";
      cout<<"\n\n\t4.About Us";
      cout<<"\n\n\t5.Admin Login";
      cout<<"\n\n\t6.EXIT";
      cout<<"\n\n--->> ";

      cin>>ch;
      return ch;
  }
  ```

  having small function will help you a lot (maintenability, readability, ...). Cores of each case of this big switch based function can be in subfunction.
- Avoid unclear variable name: `x`, `k`, ... is not really helpfull when you try to understand code
- Always initialize your variables, it's avoid bug
- (Personal point of view): one line, one variable declaration. When you declare many variables on same line, it's difficult to identify which variables exists, where there are declared, at which value there are initialized, ... Also, when you want add or remove variable it's easier if each of there is on its own line
- It's a little bit strange that class `admin` inherits from `base_pizza`: is admin of application a pizza ? of course not, so class `admin` shouldn't inherit from `base_pizza`